A relativistic fly flies at $0.7c$ in the same direction as a car traveling at $0.8c$. What will the speed of the fly be according to the driver?

A relativistic fly flies at 0.7c in the same direction as a car traveling at 0.8c. According to the driver of the car, how quickly will the fly approach the car?

To solve this problem, I applied the relativistic velocity addition formula:
$$
u' = \frac{u - v}{1 - \frac{uv}{c^2}}
$$
where
u = 0.7c and v = 0.8c. The answer that I get is 0.23c. however, the answer in my book is 0.96c. I was wondering which answer is correct, as I think the book's answer could be wrong.

Can you [edit] the name of the textbook into your question?

The question seems a bit ambiguous, since the fly (travelling at 0.7 c), won't approach the car (travelling at 0.8 c), indeed don't you get -0.23 c?

The book's answer is wrong. This is the relative speed for when they are flying in opposite directions.
